# is there a better way to write this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search and update record which start which a partcular number or fall with a range.

I have made a query which  works where values start with a particular number. I can't figure out how to do it with a range.

for example I want to update the following values in products_ean with  " "

```
255
201-230   ---> starts with 201,202,203 ...230
236
980-990   ---> starts with 980.981,982 ...990
```

I have written the following query which  works but  not sure if it is efficent espcialy when it has to serach over 100k records. It doesn't work with range.

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean ="" 
where products_ean like "200%" 
OR products_ean like "020%" 
OR products_ean like "023%" 
OR products_ean like "027%" 
OR products_ean like "042%" 
OR products_ean like "221%" 
OR products_ean like "209%" 
OR products_ean like "041%" 
OR products_ean like "049%" 
OR products_ean like "026%" 
OR products_ean like "025%" 
OR products_ean like "299%";
```

Comment: Is there any motivation behind using string field for your EAN codes? My idea would be to add column representing searched number and make a range query on that instead of using likes

Comment: If performance is the issue: denormalization (e.g. adding columns)

Comment: @fallenPhantasm EAN codes can have varying length, so this would make checking ranges more complex.

Comment: as GolezTrol mentioned. ean numbers come in different lengths..i need to remove all numbers which start with following numbers as mentioned here http://www.gs1.org/barcodes/support/prefix_list

Comment: @GolezTrol it is possible to store just few first numbers form EAN string, not the whole (I suspect that these EAN code have letters in them, so converting whole ean to number would be impossible) and range them on that basis - I know it's not that great but it would work

Comment: @fallenPhantasm: EAN can be 8 or 13 digits. In EAN13 the 3 leading digits are country codes. In EAN8 it's the leading 2 or 3. So 025xxxxxxxxxx would be the same country as 25xxxxxx as far as I understand it. It is thus likely that naf wants to delete some countries' EANs here. It is not likely that there are some EAN13 and some EAN8, for then the given algorithm would not work. Yes, one could store the country codes separately, but I suppose that it is just a one time query we are talking about here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be a full table scan anyhow, so you can use a function on `products_ean` with no loss of performance. This said, you can get the query more readable, but probably not much faster. However, you can still try whether it is faster, to take the three leading digits and compare these:

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean = '' 
where left(products_ean,3) in ('200', '020', '027', ...);
```

If you find it more readable, you can even use ranges:

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean = '' 
where left(products_ean,3) = '255'
   or left(products_ean,3) between '201' and '230'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try this not sure about performance but less code.. if your ean is a string field. you can try this

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean ="" 
where (left(products_ean,3) between 201 and 230) or
(left(products_ean,3) between 980 and 990) or
```

PS: you might want to cast the field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its going to be faster but its another alternative:

To Find:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE products_ean
REGEXP  '^(200|020|023|027|042|221|209|041|049|026|025|299)'
```

To Replace:

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean = ''
WHERE products_ean
REGEXP  '^(200|020|023|027|042|221|209|041|049|026|025|299)'
```

note: it will not use indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
UPDATE products SET products_ean = " "
WHERE STRCMP(products_ean, '200') >= 0 AND STRCMP(products_ean, '220') <= 0
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try where contains,
it must be like:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(t.products_ean, '"200*" OR "020*" OR "023*"')
```

Comment: how do i deal with ranges..201-230 .. i need to remove all record which start with 201 ,202,203..230